# Mobile Optimized site

Tags: php, css

I have to develop Mobile Optimized Website for Android, Iphone and Blackberry and Also Site for Desktop and Tablet. We know that Screen resolutions of all devices are varied one. My head instruct me to develop one site and for all devices and change css dynamically according to the devices. . Is any one know how to create such kind of site? Is any framework or cms available for this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look at "responsive websites". This is the technique you want.

E.g. http://responsejs.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries to change css depending on screen size, resolution, etc. (see [here for an example](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)).

As for frameworks .. maybe you could try http://www.getskeleton.com/ or jQuery mobile.

I would recommend that you not use pure css to style a website for mobile vs. non-mobile, though.  You should try to minimize the DOM for mobile devices to reduce download time.  This is not as much of an issue for full websites, which can benefit from a much richer DOM.

Comment: Here's a nice add-on for media queries: http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/.  This script implements media queries in a number of browsers that don't support it.  I haven't used it yet but I plan to on my next responsive design project.

Answer (score 1):

Try using adapt. It will allow you to specify different stylesheets for different ranges of device width.

http://adapt.960.gs/

I would advise against media queries as they are not supported by all browsers on different devices. Take a look here for further reading -> http://www.miqrogroove.com/blog/2012/dont-use-min-width-media-queries/

Comment: I wonder how this deals with edge cases, like 980px, given `'760px  to 980px  = 720.css', '980px  to 1280px = 960.css',`?

Comment: It takes the next one up, so its like 760px < 980px, and 980px < 1280px